# How to connect controller and mustache?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mustache, spring-rest

Having problem with sending infprmation to localhost. Using http://localhost:8080 occurs an Whitelabel Error Page (This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.) insted of showing information from mustache file. How can I solve that? Is there something wrong with connection?

Controller class:

```
import com.work.Dormitory.domain.Information;
import com.work.Dormitory.repositories.InfoRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {
@Autowired
private InfoRepository infoRepository;
    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
      model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String main(Map<String,Object> model){
        Iterable<Information> information=infoRepository.findAll();
        model.put("information",information);
        return "main";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String add(@RequestParam String numberDormitory, @RequestParam String room, Map<String,Object> model){
        Information information=new Information(numberDormitory,room);
       infoRepository.save(information);
        Iterable<Information> info=infoRepository.findAll();
        model.put("info",info);
        return "main";
    }
}
```

Repository class:

```
import com.work.Dormitory.domain.Information;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface InfoRepository extends CrudRepository<Information,Long> {
}
```

Information class:

```
package com.work.Dormitory.domain;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Information {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String room;
    private String dormitoryNumber;

    public Information(){}
    public Information(String dormitoryNumber, String room) {
        this.dormitoryNumber = dormitoryNumber;
        this.room=room;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(String room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

    public String getDormitoryNumber() {
        return dormitoryNumber;
    }

    public void setDormitoryNumber(String dormitoryNumber) {
        this.dormitoryNumber = dormitoryNumber;
    }
}
```

main.mustache:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://localhost:8080">
<body>
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="numberDormitory" placeholder="Write number of dormitory" />
        <input type="text" name="room" placeholder="Number of room: ">
        <button type="submit"> Add </button>
    </form>
</div>
<div>list </div>
  {{#messages}}
    <div>
        <b>{{id}}</b>
        <span>{{room}}</span>
        <i>{{dormitoryNumber}}</i>
    </div>
  {{/messages}}
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.work</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dormitory</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Dormitory</name>
    <description>Project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Using http://localhost:8080/greeting shows just a word "greeting" on a site insted of say "hello world" and http://localhost:8080/greeting?j showing also "greeting" instead of "hello j". Using http://localhost:8080 occurs an Whitelabel Error Page, when the form user should fill out was expected. The main problem is how to solve this Whitelabel Error Page

Answer (score 0):

You're using @RestController while you actually need @Controller. Read about server side rendering, vie resolvers in Spring.